# javascript userprofile relative path in hta file

Tags: javascript, hta

I have these two code lines in my hta file:

`iStream=fso.OpenTextFile('%USERPROFILE%/CAD_Kunde.txt',1,true);`
`oStream=fso.OpenTextFile('%USERPROFILE%/CAD_Kunde.txt',2,true);`

As you can see I tried to use a relative path but I get a `Path not found` error. How can I fix this? The JavaScript has access to the filesystem. Is it posible to write and read the (CAD_Kunde.txt) in the current userprofile? And yes it must be Javacript. I searched with Google but I didn't find something that helped me.

Comment: Shouldn't it be \ instead of `/`, since this is windows? Do those paths work from console (cmd)?

Comment: no it doesnt matter /\ i cant use this in cmd its javascript

Comment: I'm not asking you to use that as solution. I'm asking, whether is it working that way at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Propably you need this:

```
shell=new ActiveXObject('WScript.Shell');
userPath=shell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings('%UserProfile%');
```

and then:

```
iStream=fso.OpenTextFile(userPath+'/CAD_Kunde.txt',1,true);
```

WScript.Shell is very useful in HTAs, to learn more: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a74hyyw0%28v=vs.85%29.aspx